Why did I get this question on Tkinter wrong?
This question is from the PCPP course, organised by Python Institute.

From what I have learnt from the course, these answers should be correct. However, it says I got the answer partially correct, which I believe means only one of my answers is incorrect. I have consulted ChatGPT, who is saying I should get the question right, thus I would appreciate any thoughts on this. :)

I think the first and the second choice are right. "It is possible to change a callback bound to a widget", this is probably right.
Btw, the last choice sounds strange, I think that's wrong.

"callback" is such a vague phrase, I can definitely see the fourth choice as being true. A callback is just a function, and you can call functions from anywhere. Now, an event callback needs an event parameter, but even that can be synthesized if you want to call the callback. The third choice is the only one I think is definitely not true.

@BryanOakley If the callback is a method in a class or a nested function, it may not be called directly from within any part of the code.

@BryanOakley what if a callback is a lambda function? Not sure if you can then call it anywhere else.

@DanyaK: it's difficult, but not impossible. You can assign a lambda to a variable, for example. foo = lambda: some_function(1,2,3); foo()

@acw1668: sure, but the question is pretty vague about what it means by "directly". You can certainly define the callbacks such that they are directly callable.   The answers really depend on how the question defines "callback". I think the bottom line is that it's a poorly worded question.

widget.bind() should work to replace the command with a command.

I think the question might have been implied on a more basic level, as all the comments here are valid, but not covered in the course for some peculiar reason. I just hope the actual exam questions are less vague!

Call backs cannot be called from any part of the code. The self. reference is meaningless without a binding. For instance, reading values from widgets.
def retrieve_input():
    input = self.myText_Box.get("1.0",'end-1c')

